# Core data always deletes first object

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I am using swiftUI in my app that uses coredata to store FoodItems. In my app I have a list of all the foodItems stored on the users device. Supposedly they are supposed to be able to delete any one of the foodItems by long holding and pressing either eat or throw away, but each time I try to delete any of the foodItems, it always deletes the first one in the list instead of the one I long holded. Can anyone help me? Here is a snippet of my code:

```
    ForEach(self.storageIndex.foodItemArray, id:\.self) { item in

    RefrigeratorItemCell(icon: item.wrappedSymbol, title: item.wrappedName, lastsUntil: self.addDays(days: Int(item.wrappedStaysFreshFor), dateCreated: item.wrappedInStorageSince))
        .gesture(LongPressGesture()
            .onEnded({ i in
                self.showEatActionSheet.toggle()
            })
    )
        //TODO: Make a diffrence between eat all and throw away
        .actionSheet(isPresented: self.$showEatActionSheet, content: {
            ActionSheet(title: Text("More Options"), message: Text("Chose what to do with this food item"), buttons: [
                .default(Text("Eat All"), action: {
                    self.managedObjectContext.delete(item)
                    try? self.managedObjectContext.save()
                })
                ,.default(Text("Throw Away"), action: {
                    self.managedObjectContext.delete(item)
                    try? self.managedObjectContext.save()
                })

                ,.default(Text("Cancel"))
            ])
        })

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use instead `.actionSheet(item:` and move it out of `ForEach` cycle, as on below scratchy example

```
@State private var foodItem: FoodItem? // << tapped item (use your type)

// .. other code

VStack {     // << some your parent container
    ForEach(self.storageIndex.foodItemArray, id:\.self) { item in

        RefrigeratorItemCell(icon: item.wrappedSymbol, title: item.wrappedName, lastsUntil: self.addDays(days: Int(item.wrappedStaysFreshFor), dateCreated: item.wrappedInStorageSince))
            .gesture(LongPressGesture()
                .onEnded({ i in
                    self.foodItem = item      // << tapped item
                })
        )
            //TODO: Make a diffrence between eat all and throw away
    }
} // actionSheet attach to parent
.actionSheet(item: self.$foodItem, content: { item in // << activated on item
    ActionSheet(title: Text("More Options"), message: Text("Chose what to do with this food item"), buttons: [
        .default(Text("Eat All"), action: {
            self.managedObjectContext.delete(item)
            try? self.managedObjectContext.save()
        })
        ,.default(Text("Throw Away"), action: {
            self.managedObjectContext.delete(item)
            try? self.managedObjectContext.save()
        })

        ,.default(Text("Cancel"))
    ])
})
```

Comment: once I do that it shows the error, "Instance method 'actionSheet(item:content:)' requires that 'FoodItem' conform to 'Identifiable'"

Comment: @RyanD, FoodItem was just a stub name in my code as you did not provide your types, but of course if it required to conform it to Identifiable, then you should conform it. To have copy-paste solution, you need to provide copy-paste testable code, otherwise adapting answer is on you. ;)

Comment: alright thanks, but would i be able to confirm it to identifiable if it is an entity from core data?     "@FetchRequest(entity: FoodItem.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \FoodItem.staysFreshFor, ascending: true)]) var foodItem: FetchedResults<FoodItem>"

Comment: @RyanD, sure, if you don't have explicit field that uniquely identify food item it is possible to use `self` as id, because it is actually objective-c reference type object.