# SwiftUI - Wrong index with removeAll(where: )

Tags: swiftui

I want to let the user remove an image in an array. When the image is pressed, an action sheet is presented so the user can confirm the removal of the image. The problem is that it removes the wrong image. It always removes the first image of the array.

```
@State var pickerResult: [SImage] = []

...

ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: true){
  HStack{
    ForEach(pickerResult) { simage in
      Image(uiImage: simage.image)
        .onTapGesture() {
          imageActionSheetIsPresented = true
          // This will work: self.pickerResult.removeAll(where: {$0.image == simage.image})
        }
        .actionSheet(isPresented: $imageActionSheetIsPresented) {
          ActionSheet(title: Text("Do you want to remove the image?"), buttons: [
            .default(Text("Remove image")){
              self.pickerResult.removeAll(where: {$0.image == simage.image})
              print(simage.id)
              // Returns id of the first image in the array
            },
            .cancel()
          ])
        }
    }
  }
}
```

As you see in the code, skipping the confirmation and letting the user remove the image with onTap will work just fine.
Some how 'simage' is always the first item in the array when using ActionSheet.

Here is the SImage:

```
struct SImage: Identifiable{
    var id = UUID()
    var image: UIImage
}
```

Comment: Your problem is similar as solved in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61976436/12299030 - wrong place of action sheet attached.

Comment: Yup, that solved it! Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. You can vote that answer up to make it more visible for others.